# Can you make 1 = 2 in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Now this may sound like a bizarre question to ask but I'm wondering if there is anyway I could possible make 1 equate 2. For example if I write 11 in a cell, I want it to show 11 but actually equate to 22. I've thought of other ways to do this but It won't show the true  value of what I'm trying to show. I don't know if this is possible but I would like the communities help on this one.

Comment: This is an instance where it will be more helpful if you explain WHY you want to do something rather than merely WHAT you want to do. The more context you can give behind the reason for this, the higher the likelihood that someone here will be able to offer a meaningful suggestion.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with an example of the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Do `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"1","2")`

Have a try and share if it works/not..